# Are compilers OS-specific?

Tags: compiler-construction, operating-system, specifications

I understand what a compiler does, in that it takes source code and compiles it to machine code that the computer can understand. However, I'm wondering one thing, which is that, is that machine code specific to every different operating system? Is it necessary to write a different compiler for the same language on Mac, Windows and Linux operating systems? Please elaborate if the answer is yes, no or in between.

Answer (score 9):

It depends.

A compiler that generates machine instructions is *machine* (or *architecture*) specific: an ARM and an x86 have different instruction sets, so the machine code would be very different for each, but it's not *necessarily* OS-dependent (although it usually is, because different OSes have different calling conventions, etc.) The *linker* component is almost always OS-specific, since this is what creates the executable file for that OS. Not all compiler systems separate the compiler from the linker -- if it's one program, than it would be OS-specific.

However, there are OS/machine independent compilers: most notably Java (and other JVM-based languages, such as Scala or Groovy). This is because Java compilers generate *bytecode* for the JVM, and are executed by the Java runtime (which *is* OS and processor specific). But the Java compiler (which is written in Java) can run on any machine, and generate code that will run on any machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This brings me to another area of confusion that I had, which is about the JVM. By OS-independent (in the second part), do you mean different compilers for different OS's? I'm confused because you say that the Java compiler is OS-independent, but then you say that the Java compiler will run on any machine. I'm pretty confused in general about the JVM - which steps in the process are OS-specific, and which will run on any machine?

Comment: @user8768055.Simple programs without functions or procedures that you write in a high level language that doesn't require any input or output probably will gets translated by a compiler to specific machine code for the given computer architecture (regardless the OS). Now, programs that you write in high level language that uses any I/O or has functions or procedures, they also will get translated to the specific machine code for the given computer architecture AND the I/O operations and the calling routines will be translated having into account the given OS that provides support+functionality

Answer (score 2):

The output from a compilation contains two things
1. Calls to operating system library routines
2. Native machine code to perform your "business logic"

The second part is, most likely, identical for every compilation that targets a specific processor architecture (why shouldn't it be if you're using the same version of GCC).

The calls to library routines are where things fall down. That's the reason WINE exists on Linux - it's to give you some "emulated" / "translated" routines that run on Linux to give you a way to run a Windows program on an alien operating system.

So the answer is really, not quite. Rather than an absolute yes or no.

Answer (score -1):

keep in mind that compilers running on one OS can generate code for a different OS.

So if i write a compiler for OS A, and it can generate core for OS B, then I can compile that compiler written for A, but output for B.  then i have a compiler for B.    Technically some might not call it the same compiler.

Comment: do note that the thing being described above is called "cross compiler"